# How to apply CSS class in dynamic cell template of grid-ui in controller using AngularJs 1.5

Tags: css, angularjs

I am having an issue in applying CSS Class in controller class cell template.
Having an issue in \'this.styles.test\'

```
$onInit() {
    this.testTemplate ='<div ng-class="{\'this.styles.test\':{{row.entity.test===\'active\'}}}">/div>';
}
```

test.css

```
.test { 
    background-image: url(/images/note_edit.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: left center; 
    display: block; 
    height: 20px; 
    width: 20px; 
}
```

testController.js

```
import styles from './test.css'; 
class TestController { 

    /*@ngInject;*/ 
    constructor() { 
      this.styles = styles; 
    }; 
    $onInit() {
         this.testTemplate ='<div ng-class="{\'this.styles.test\':{{row.entity.test===\'active??\'}}}"></div>'; 
    }   
} 
export default TestController;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it contains a clear problem statement and the necessary code. It's difficult to see what you're asking.

Comment: @4castle : Thanks. I have edited the code. I am using angularjs 1.5 i.e. using component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using 'styles.test' instead of 'this.styles.test'
 We are using webpack that bundle all the css and assign a unique name. 
If we use 'this.styles.test' transpiler unable to find test css class. We have an object of styles when page load, we can use that object and can access the css class.

The correct usage of css class is mentioned below :

```
$onInit() {
         this.testTemplate ='<div ng-class="{\'styles.test\':{{row.entity.test===\'active??\'}}}"></div>'; 
    }
```